# Why Download button not working with ajax php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I hava a problem. It is my sincere honor if anyone helps.

I have a webpage created with php (called mypage.php). I want to have 2 exactly identical download buttons in this webpage; one available after the page is loaded or refreshed completely and the other one loads in ajax mode after another button is clicked.
Now, the first download button works great (which means it will download the file after clicking) but the ajax one is not working.
In fact, I could connect the client side and server side, load my button.php file, get the response from server and see the second (ajax) download button in my webpage. but, unfotunately, it seems that for the ajax download button, just html and css are working. I mean if you click on the ajax download button, it does not download the file.

My codes are as below:

the html code of my first download button written as html in my main webpage (mypage.php):

```html
<button class="gray doPrint" id="admin-sub-download-button" data-dp="download" data-func="download">Download </button>
```

the javascript code to load button.php file that holds the code of the second (ajax) download button:

```js
    <script>
      function replaceText() {
        var target = document.getElementById("mydivbutton");
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/woodmart/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/core/includes/button.php', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          console.log('readyState: ' + xhr.readyState);
          if(xhr.readyState == 1) {
            target.innerHTML = 'Loading11...';
          }
          if(xhr.readyState == 2) {
            target.innerHTML = 'Loading22...';
          }
          if(xhr.readyState == 3) {
            target.innerHTML = 'Loading33...';
          }
          if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            target.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
          }
        }
        xhr.send();
      }

      var button1 = document.getElementById ("mydownloadbutton");
      button1.addEventListener("click", replaceText);
    </script>
```

button.php code:

```js
<?php
echo ('<button class="gray doPrint" id="admin-sub-download-button" data-dp="download" data-func="download">Download </button>');    
?>
```

The second download button (ajax download button) is added to html div as below:

```html
<div id="mydivbutton">result</div>
```

It is highly appreciated if anyone helps.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your ID for the 1st button is  id="mydivbutton" while in your code example you are using it as : var button1 = document.getElementById ("mydownloadbutton");

Can you update your code with correct IDs so people can relate it?

Points to note:
1) If you are loading some element from ajax, you need to make sure that you are binding the events after the response is added to DOM.
2) Try adding a onclick alert() and see if it works.

Comment: Because it has no event listener attached.

Comment: Thanks very much. for the id, I think they are right. when I click on button with id="mydownloadbutton", the request is sent to server to load the button.php file. In button.php file, I have an html code for a button with id="admin-sub-download-button". this html code is similar to my first download button with id="admin-sub-download-button" which is loaded on page refresh(not ajax)